# OpenSL ES VS MediaRecorder / AudioRecord

Tags: android, audio

In terms of audio recording, is there an advantage for using OpenSL ES instead of API recorders (MediaREcorder / AudioRecord)?
Are there options that can be utilized to produce better quality / use wider range of devices? 
Can OpenSL-ES support more options / sources if device is rooted?